# UIWebView, Word office document and pagination

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

When UIWebView loads Microsoft word documents, it just loads it as if it's one whole strip of paper, disregarding the separation between pages.  Any idea how to display it properly (pages separated from each other), I'm open to lower level programming, or alternatives to UIWebView for loading Office documents.  I'm currently using IPhone OS 3.2 for IPad.

E.g. I tried creating a word document with 2 pages, and one paragraph on each page, when I load it in UIWebView, it's displayed in one page.

The code I used is from [Apple Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html)

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

// Calling -loadDocument:inView:
[self loadDocument:@"test1.doc" inView:self.myWebview];
```

As a side note, I'm thinking this should be possible because there are apps like Documents to Go and QuickOffice, I'm not sure how they implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current SDK, it's not possible.  We ended up implementing our own and used UIScrollView to meet our requirements.  This was a lot of work implementing our own renderer, own panning system, etc.

Comment: is it possible to render doc file's? could you please share how can I do this? some references. I also had lot of issues in loading document file in webview like some doc files are fail to load.

Comment: For guys looking at a better document viewer, you should try doing your research at crocodoc, which is box' document renderer.  Crocodoc is api based by the way so the rendering happens in web which you will capture with a webview